# java compiler in Android studio 3.2 and 3.3 canary 13 shows a lot of warning

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

When updating Android studio, after built many warning are shown, and I couldn't ignore them, I tried to resolve them but I didn't find any way, so is there any solution and what should I update?

Android Studio 3.2

gralde plugin version : classpath 
 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'

app.gradle 
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

log

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you can see, it is because android studio has updated few things so better not to use them otherwise they will work, ignore the warnings